# Use join with CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which i am inserting some records every week. There is a column for Date. I want to compare the data of last week and this week using column key. Below is my table:

```
Name   Date         Key
ABC    07 June       1
BAC    07 June       2
WSD    07 June       3
QWE    14 June       9
QWT    14 June       2
DEF    14 June       1
CXZ    14 June       6
```

I want the data of 14 June in which key is same as in data of 07th june.

Desired output:

```
Name   Date         Key
QWT    14 June       2
DEF    14 June       1
```

I am using CTE to join but i am not getting the desired results.

```
;WITH T1 
AS
(SELECT * FROM   [Table] where [Date]= '07 June'),
T2 
AS
(SELECT * FROM   [Table] where [Date]= '14 June')
SELECT *
FROM T2
INNER JOIN T1 ON T1.[KEY] = T2.[KEY];
```

Comment: It looks right to me. The only change would be `SELECT T2.* FROM T2 INNER JOIN...` so that only `T2` records flow into your output. Another option would be `SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Date] = '14 June' AND Key IN (SELECT Key FROM [Table] WHERE [Date] = '07 June')` (or referencing your CTE in place of those...

Comment: What is the desire result and what result are you getting?

Comment: This might be worth a read since you are storing dates as varchar. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should be returning the results you stated that you want. I would maybe simplify this a little bit to a single query with a self join. Something like this.

```
select t2.*
from [Table] t
join [Table] t2 on t.MyKey = t2.MyKey
where t.MyDate = '07 June' 
    and t2.MyDate = '14 June'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data of 14 June in which key is the same as in data of 07th June. You can use `intersect`:

```
select
    t1.*
from
    table
        as t1
    where
        t1.MyDate = '07 June'
intersect select
        t2.*
    from
        table
            as t2
        where
            t2.MyDate = '14 June
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also think everything dynamic as below. This will return you result regardless what is the date is. this will always compare a row with the row with date 7 day less.

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03cfc68229e38747cfb5901a7ef1e6aa)

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN your_table B 
ON A.[Key] = B.[Key] AND DATEADD(DD,7,B.[Date]+ ' 2019') = A.[Date] + ' 2019' 
-- Added 2019 To make the string as date
```

Comment: Not sure I'd suggest this way as you're creating a non sargable join statement where every row would need to be analyzed, on large tables this would be very slow.